# Getting a value in PHP from MySQL and if there's no record - inserting it

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've got the following code:

```
<?php
include 'payment/dbConfig.php';
$email = $_GET['email'];
$account = $_GET['account'];
if($email != ''){
    $sql = "SELECT command FROM bots WHERE email='".$email."' AND account='".$account."' limit 1";;
    $result = $db->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $value = $row["command"];
        }
    }

    if($value != ''){
       echo $value;
       $sql = "UPDATE `bots` SET command='' WHERE email='".$email."' AND account='".$account."'";
       $db->query($sql);
    }else{
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `bots`(`email`, `account`) VALUES ('".$email."','".$account."')";
        $db->query($sql);
    }
}
?>
```

Which definitely looks like a mess, and this isn't working right.
Specifically, it endlessly adds the same `'email'` and `'account'` into the database, even though it should be done only when `$value` is not equal to emptiness.

What should I do?

Comment: use like this 
if(empty($value)){
//insert
}else{
//update
}

Comment: @Shibon didn't solve the issue, the same thing happens

Comment: $result->num_rows echo and check the count

Comment: I'm actually an idiot, I just realized it kept happening because the mysql record kept having the value of  nothingness. Thanks for help anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in less code.

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // Update
    $sql = "UPDATE `bots` SET command='' WHERE email='".$email."' AND account='".$account."'";
   $db->query($sql);
} else {
    // Insert
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `bots`(`email`, `account`) VALUES ('".$email."','".$account."')";
    $db->query($sql);
}
```

Note: You are passing the user inputs ($_GET) directly in the query, [Sanitize](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.examples.sanitization.php) all user inputs ($_GET, $_POST) and check for [SQL Injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp) before execute any query.